# AppLinks setup not working via Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, deep-linking, applinks

I have created a new single view app and all I did was assign it's custom url scheme to be "deeplink"

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string> (I tried without this too)
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>deeplink</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

and I have an html file hosted on my website with the following:

```
<html>
        <head>
                <meta property="fb:app_id" content="########" /> (I even tried with a Facebook app id and without it)
                <meta property="al:iphone:url" content="deeplink://test" />
                <meta property="og:title" content="Hello Deeplink" />
                <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
                <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
        </head>
        <body>
                Hello, world!
        </body>
</html>
```

When I click a link through the Facebook app (i.e. a post) or via a message on Facebook messenger, it opens the Facebook built-in browser and it does not try to open the app, it only shows "Hello, world!" in the browser. I am able to open the app by navigating to deeplink://example from safari though. I think this is all the setup that app links needs, am I missing something? is there a reason why this is not working?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: This might not be done automatic. Facebook is constantly experimenting with this feature, however if it's setup correctly the option to open your app might appear on one of the buttons they have on the in app browser, can you confirm? it should look like a tilted rectangle (last time I checked)

Comment: you are missing a lot of required tags in your HTML http://applinks.org/documentation/#publishingapplinks